# Vertical space created from float

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to understand floats better. I do not understand this issue. I have had it occur in a few cases but this is my most recent. I am making a two-column unordered list but have some issues with vertical spacing.

```
<ul>
<li width="50%"> a bunch of text</li>
<li width="50%"> a very large amount of text</li>
<li width="50%"> a small amount of text that does not line up with the first li</li>
</ul>
```

See code snippet for a proper demonstration.

```css
.lists ul{
    width:500px;
}
li{
    width: 40%;
    float:left;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">harpoons sticking in near his starb</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> aaalewent milling and milling round so, that my boat's crew could only trim dish, by sitting all thing and milling round so, that my boat's crew could only trim dish, by sitting all theiwent milling and milling round so, that my boat's crew could only trim dish, by sitting all thei, with a milky-white head and </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> five whales, and my boat fastened to one of them; a regular circus horse he was, too, that r sterns on the outer gunwale. </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> harpoons sticking in near his starb went milling and milling round so, that my boat's crew could only trim dish, by sitting all thei </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> m the bottom went milling and milling round so, that my boat's crew could only trim dish, by sitting all theiwent milling and milling round so, that my boat's crew could only trim dish, by sitting all theiof </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> harpoons sticking in near his starb </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to remove the vertical gap between the first and second item in the first column, although I don't understand why it exists.

I need to support IE 8 and make an effort for IE7.

Comment: That's just how floats behave.  Are you simply doing this because your want your list items to have a mulit-column layout?

Comment: yes, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to understand floats as well, but with a recent project I really got a grasp of them.

If you notice in your fiddle, your #1 and #2 are floated correctly.  The #3 li is then floated to the left in the next available space.  Unfortunately, floats do not allow elements (like #3 li) to be placed in that available space.  It does not allow for 'back fill'.  You see, your #2 element is taller than your #1, so it creates that small gap that you are seeing.  The next available position for your #3 element to go is under your first element, but that space is technically taken, so it pushes it down.

You can do a two column layout by making two lists and not floating any of it, just styling the `ul`s to be the right width.

Or you can float every other div to the right

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to keep them all in one list but it looks like that is just not something I will be able to do.

Comment: Well, it seems there are some answers above that allow you to keep it to one list.  You will have to use `:nth-child()` if you are able to use CSS3.  If not, I would suggest using two lists.

Comment: Technically you could also use javascript to position them correctly.  but this is a pretty major undertaking.

Answer (score 5):

A nice way of producing two columns in one `<ul>` tag is this

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/NChgL/1/

```
div#multiColumn {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

I discovered this some time ago and have been using it ever since.

EDITED

Another solution is to float one `<li>` left and the other one right and so forth (but does not support IE8 and earlier)

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/NChgL/3/

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    float: left;
}
```

But you could assign a class to each `<li>`. One for the left and one for the right and it would have the same effect as above.

Comment: Thanks, this is great but I need to support IE8 and make an effort for IE7 so I think CSS3 tags will remain a bit of a dream for me.

Comment: I understand your concern. Floats will not give the same effect with the use of a single `<ul>`. YOur float is leaving that gap as it is inline with the opposing `<li>` item, this is how floats behave. Could you use two `<ul>` lists and then float one of them? this would be fully compatible with the browsers you need to support.

Comment: @gBoat If you have specific browser requirements, you need to specify them up front.  Browsers that lack support for `columns` degrade gracefully.  There's no good alternate solution that will allow you to support antique browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to align them properly.

Hope this may help- http://masonry.desandro.com/

It also works in IE.

Comment: It says that page not found.

Comment: I simply suggested to go for Masonry effect. It allow to stack the items on the empty spaces. you may explore the options here https://github.com/desandro/masonry